# Web API 2 routing attributes not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm using the final release versions of .NET 4.5 and Web API 2 (in Visual Studio 2013). I've been using [this documentation](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Attribute%20routing%20in%20MVC%20and%20Web%20API&referringTitle=Specs) as a reference, to no avail.

I have a few base routes like

```
api/providers
api/locations
api/specialties
```

And some methods on each like

```
Get()
Get(int id)
Get(string keyword)
Autocomplete(string keyword)
Search(string zipcode, string name, int radius, [...])
```

Ideally, I'd like the URLs to end up like

- **/api/locations/12345** (get location 12345)
- **/api/locations/clinical** (get locations with "clinical" in the name)
- **/api/locations/autocomplete?keyword=clinical**
  (get a condensed Id + Name object for locations with "clinical" in the name)
- **/api/locations/search?zipcode=12345&radius=20&name=clinical**
  (get locations within 20 miles of zip 12345 with "clinical" in the name)

In the chunk of code below, the `Get` methods and `Search` work as desired, but `Autocomplete` does not. It should be noted I have similarly named methods in multiple controllers. What am I doing wrong? (Also, what exactly is the `Name =` property for?)

```
/// <summary>
/// This is the API used to interact with location information.
/// </summary>
[RoutePrefix("api/locations")]
public class LocationController : ApiController
{
    private ProviderEntities db = new ProviderEntities();

    private static readonly Expression<Func<Location, LocationAutocompleteDto>> AsLocationAutocompleteDto =
        x => new LocationAutocompleteDto
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = x.Name
        };

    /// <summary>
    /// Get ALL locations.
    /// </summary>
    [Route("")]
    public IQueryable<Location> Get()
    {
        return db.Locations.AsQueryable();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get a specific location.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">The ID of a particular location.</param>
    [Route("{id:int}")]
    public IQueryable<Location> Get(int id)
    {
        return db.Locations.Where(l => l.Id == id);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get all locations that contain a keyword.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="keyword">The keyword to search for in a location name.</param>
    [Route("{keyword:alpha}")]
    public IQueryable<Location> Get(string keyword)
    {
        return db.Locations.Where(l => l.Name.Contains(keyword)).OrderBy(l => l.Name);
    }

    [Route("search", Name = "locationsearch")]
    public string Search(string zipcode = null, string latitude = null, string longitude = null)
    {
        if (zipcode != null) return "zipcode";
        if (latitude != null && longitude != null) return "lat/long";
        else
            return "invalid search";
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Autocomplete service for locations, returns simple Id/Name pairs.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="keyword">The keyword to search on.</param>
    [Route("autocomplete/{keyword:alpha}", Name = "locationautocomplete")]
    public IQueryable<LocationAutocompleteDto> Autocomplete(string keyword)
    {
        // validate the inputs
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword))
            return null;

        IQueryable<Location> results = from l in db.Locations
                                       where l.Name.Contains(keyword)
                                       select l;

        return results.Select(AsLocationAutocompleteDto);
    }
```

There does not seem to be a lot of community support around the latest versions of this stuff yet.

## EDIT (with answer)

Simply replaced

```
[Route("autocomplete/{keyword:alpha}", Name = "locationautocomplete")]
```

with

```
[Route("autocomplete"), Route("autocomplete/{keyword:alpha}", HttpGet()]
```

and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you trying to do a GET request on Search and AutoComplete actions? If yes, then you would need to decorate with a `System.Web.Http.HttpGet` attribute. If an action isn't prefixed by verbs like Get, Put, Post, Delete etc, Web API by defaults assumes as POST. I am guessing you are receiving a 405 Method Not Allowed..right?

The Name property is useful in case of link generation (`Url.Link`) where you would need to specify a name

Comment: Thank you!!

I changed `[Route("autocomplete/{keyword:alpha}", Name = "locationautocomplete")]` to `[Route("autocomplete"), Route("autocomplete/{keyword:alpha}"), HttpGet()]` and it works perfectly now.

The `HttpGet()` attribute was key, and chaining the two `Route()` definitions together makes it work in the two different ways I desired.